# Removing event listeners before delete of the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events, vue-directives

Question regarding this solution:
[Dynamically add and remove classes on mouseover - Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892189/dynamically-add-and-remove-classes-on-mouseover-vue-js/57867618#57867618)

The directive works fine, thanks! But when I use it on some component that's being destroyed (deleted from it's parent array with a hover-visible button), I get an error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in directive add-class-hover unbind hook: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present."

Which makes sense, because the unbinding happens after the component part gets removes (as the hover is no longer detected).

How does one remove this binding, so the console stays non-red? beforeDestroy doesn't seem to work for directives. So is there a trick to call a "remove all listeners of component and it's children".

Comment: Is there a reason you did not consider the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, I require the functionality at several places, so I thought doing a directive is the cleaner way. Wondering if the accepted answer throws an error on removal, as the @mouseover is technically a listener too… Will try.

Comment: If the listener is placed on the element you are destroying there is no need to remove it. Once the element is gone nothing will be able to trigger any event on it. You only need to clean up (remove any bound listeners) when you place listeners on a different element (some parent or `window`). You can use `beforeDestroy` hook to remove the listener, but it's bloat (if the listener is on the element about to be destroyed). There's no need to clean something that will effectively cease to exist in the next tick. You're only running extra code for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

**In vue js**

Pass `event` with `null` value.

```
Vue.directive('add-hover-class', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    const {
      value = ""
    } = binding;
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      el.classList.add(value)
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      el.classList.remove(value)
    });
  },
  unbind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.removeEventListener('mouseenter', null);
    el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', null);
  }
})
```